# Find general form of eigenvalues of a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

I have an $n \times n$ matrix in a general form:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha^{n-1} & 1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \dots & \alpha^{n-2} \\
  \alpha^{n-2} & \alpha^{n-1} & 1 & \alpha & \dots & \alpha^{n-3} \\
  \alpha^{n-3} & \alpha^{n-2} & \alpha^{n-1} & 1 & \dots & \alpha^{n-4} \\
  \alpha^{n-4} & \alpha^{n-3} & \alpha^{n-2} & \alpha^{n-1} & \dots & \alpha^{n-5} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \alpha^3 & \dots & \alpha^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix},$$

where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is some parameter. Is there a chance to have eigenvalues of this matrix in some general form (as an expression in $n$ and $\alpha$)? Or, at least, is that possible to say something about them?

I tried to numerically generate some of them but I don't really see any pattern.
[image]

Comment: Since the sum of elements of each row is the same, $1+\alpha+\ldots +\alpha^{n-1}=\dfrac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}$, you are guaranteed to have always $\dfrac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Moreover, this will be the spectral radius of $A$, i. e., all other eigenvalues will be less than $\dfrac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}$ in absolute value. Also, by Gershgorin circles, every eigenvalue $\lambda$ will fulfill $\alpha^{n-1}-\dfrac{1-\alpha^{n-1}}{1-\alpha}\leq|\lambda|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notably, $A$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). As such, its eigenvalues will be of the form
$$
\lambda_j = \alpha^{n-2}\omega^{(n-1)j} + \cdots + \alpha \omega^{2j} + \omega^j +\alpha^{n-1},
$$
where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/n}$ and $j = 0,1,\dots,n-1$. We can simplify $\lambda_j$ to
$$
\lambda_j = \alpha^{-1}((\alpha \omega^j)^{n-1} + \cdots + (\alpha \omega^j)^2 + (\alpha \omega^j) + 1) + \alpha^{n-1} - 1
\\ = \alpha^{-1}\frac{1-(\alpha \omega^j)^n}{1-\alpha\omega^j} + \alpha^{n-1} - 1\\
= \frac{1-\alpha^n \omega^{jn}}{\alpha - \alpha^2 \omega^j} + \alpha^{n-1} - 1.
$$
For $j = 0$, this yields the real eigenvalue
$$
\lambda_0 = 1 + \alpha + \cdots + \alpha^{n-1} = \frac{1 - \alpha^n}{1 - \alpha}.
$$

Comment: Actually, after posting this, I went to ask the same question from my colleague - and she was able to point me exactly this result. :)